# Binance Smart Chain Full Node Implementation - geth is not recognized (Error)

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, binance, full-node

I am trying to install Binance network,by following the official link
https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html

[image]

However, while trying to run *make geth*  I find the below error.

[image]

They point out several ways for exampkle download the binaries

## Linux

```
wget  https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/releases/download/v1.0.7/geth_linux
```

However, this does not recognize geth after it. Can I just simply use to install geth ethereum instead? Normally, that geth should not have the changes made by Binance.

Comment: You are missing the c compiler. How did you install go?

Comment: I use the this link, https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: Did you made the required modification to GOPATH and PATH environment variables?

Comment: I just use this command thats it,               
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

Comment: Did you search for the exact error message? Here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27303#issuecomment-504964623 they mention that adding to the environment `CGO_ENABLED=0` solved it.

Comment: Yes It does work. Thanks a lot. I cant accept the answer since I do not have the minimum reputation. I will accept it once my reputation is ok. However, I got another issue while installing and for that I will create another question.

Comment: Just a question, Did you implement Binance Private network?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used that network yet.